# Can't expression in switch statement be string? C++

Tags: c++

Code below return error: switch quantity not an integer. What's wrong?

```
string s = "20";
  
  switch (s){
    
    case "18":
      cout << "18" << "\n";
      break;
      
    case "20":
      cout << "20" << "\n";
      break;
    
  }
```

Comment: no it can't, as your cases are numbers why not use numbers?

Answer (score 2):

The `case`s have to be integral types and compile time evaluable constant expressions.

Rather than fighting the language, use an `if` `else` block. Or if you can use integral types, then do so:

```
int n = 20;  
switch (n){    
case 18:
    std::cout << n << "\n";
    break;      
case 20:
    std::cout << n << "\n";
    break;    
}
```

noting that the `ostream` `<<` operator has an overload for `int`.